# Radar correlators and matched filters

Tags: radar

I'm trying to understand the real-world construction of 1950's radar correlators. The articles on the topic I have seen so far are jargon-filled explanations with no real-world examples. Does anyone know of a better introduction?

Looking over the ones I've found, it *appears* that the basic idea is that you have a bunch of tunable bandpass filters connected to a series of delays so that each filter receives a small amount of the signal sampled over a short time slot.

The system is first set up by feeding through the sample signal, which in the case of radar I assume is simply an attenuated version of the transmission. This results in the filters being set to a series of values. Then you take the receiver's output and send it in and measure the output, then change all filters up or down by the same amount and repeat looking for the maximum output.

Is that basically it? If so, how do you send the received sample back through the filter network again? Is there some sort of storage loop like a delay line? I'm really curious how they built the Winkle system in the UK, if anyone knows how they did it electronically I'd love to hear.

**UPDATE: Adding links:**
http://www.radartutorial.eu/10.processing/sp54.en.html
http://www.radartutorial.eu/10.processing/Matched%20Filter.en.html
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matched_filter
http://ee.eng.usm.my/eeacad/mandeep/EEE436/chp%203.pdf